# How do I solve the differential equation for the motion of pendulum?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In order to determine the equation for displacement, we need to solve the following second order differential equation: 
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-g\sin \left(\frac{x}{l}\right)$$
where $\theta = x/l$. I am not sure how to get started on this.

Comment: This differential equation has a notoriously complex solution that provides little physical insight. Since we are often interested in the case where $\theta = x / l \ll 1$, we often approximate $\sin(x / l) \approx x / l$.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what paulinho said in the comments, we first approximate that $\sin(\frac{x}{l})\approx\frac{x}{l}$, meaning our equation reduces to: 
$$ x'' +\frac{gx}{l}=0$$
This is a homogeneous second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients and auxiliary polynomial $t^2+\frac{g}{l}$. This can be rewritten as $(t-\frac{i\sqrt{g}}{\sqrt{l}})(t+\frac{i\sqrt{g}}{\sqrt{l}})$. It follows that the following set should be a basis for the solution space:
$$ \{e^{it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}},e^{-it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}\}\longrightarrow \{\cos t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}},\sin t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}\}$$
Since 
$$ \cos t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}+e^{-it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}\right)\quad\textrm{and}\quad \sin t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}-e^{-it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}\right)$$
it follows that $\{\cos t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}},\sin t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}\}$ should be a basis for the solution space since if $\{x,y\}$ is a basis for a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, then so is $\{\frac{1}{2}(x+y),\frac{1}{2i}(x+y)\}$ and we would prefer this basis since we are familiar with sine and cosine. Thus we know that the solution should be of the form:
$$x(t)=c_1 \cos t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}+c_2\sin t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}\quad c_2,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: That approximation is an $approximation$. It is $not$ the solution, just an approximation to it. The actual solution is a non-elementary function.

Comment: @P.Lawrence indeed

Comment: Since $e^{it\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}=cos(t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}})+isin(t\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}})$, why did you kill the imaginary part off?

Comment: @DevDhruv ive edited my answer, does that make it clear that we are not killing off any imaginary part? We are simply using a more convenient choice of basis of sine and cosine via the identities mentioned.

Comment: @DevDhruv glad you understand now

Comment: Yes, I understand you chose a different basis with the same span.